# android expanded notification view

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app that puts the date in the status bar, but in order to make it look decent, I have to use two notifications.  This causes it to use two expanded notifications when you pull down the status bar.  Is there any way to get rid of one of the expanded views(or both of them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to get rid of one of
>   the expanded views(or both of them)?

No, sorry.